# Fetch values from plist file on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, osx, perl

I have bash script which was written for OS X and now ported to Linux. I don't have access to the Linux box. The bash script would read values from plist files using the `defaults read` and `PlistBuddy` command available on OS X.

Since the Linux machine doesn't have these commands, I'm looking for workarounds. Is there library/script (Perl preferably) that helps user fetch values from plist files for a given key on a Linux machine?

I tried using `sed`/`awk`, but the output isn't reliable. I've come across scripts like `plutil.pl` that convert a plist file to other formats.

I have installed a Virtual machine running Ubuntu on my Mac so that I can test my changes before deploying to the actual Linux box.

Comment: Which programs on Linux do you expect to make use of plists? I haven't come across any in the last 12 years of Linux use on a daily basis.

Comment: The linux machine hosts folders that have plist files in them. No programs on the Linux machine are going to use them.But I need to create a report on those folders and hence need to find a way to read values from the plist file on the Linux env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.plist` files are already XML (or can be easily converted) you just need something to decode the XML.

For that use `xml2`:

```
$ cat com.apple.systemsound.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.sound.beep.volume</key>
    <real>1</real>
</dict>
</plist>
$ xml2 < com.apple.systemsound.plist
/plist/@version=1.0
/plist/dict/key=com.apple.sound.beep.volume
/plist/dict/real=1
$
```

You should be able to figure out the rest.

Or for Perl, `use XML::Simple;` (see `perldoc` for more) to put the XML data structure into a hash.

Answer (score 12):

libplist seems to meet your requirements.
There is a Ubuntu package name "libplist-utils" that you could reference in your script:

> Description-en: Apple property list converter
>        This package containt tools to convert Apple property list files from binary
>        to XML and vice-versa. It's part of the libimobiledevice stack, providing
>        access to iDevices (iPod, iPhone, iPad ...).

Homepage: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

Install command:

```
apt-get install libplist-utils
```

Usage example:

```
plistutil -i Info.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

Python3 has a standard library for that:

`plistlib` can read and write `.plist` files, https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/plistlib.html

E.g. Get the value of `MyKey` from `./Info.plist`:

```
$ python3 -c "import plistlib; print(plistlib.load(open('./Info.plist', 'rb'))['MyKey'])" 
MyValue
```

This will work on any OS that runs python3.